# How to point node http server to show files inside a folders

Tags: node.js, http

I have written the code to run a simple server using the node http module. My scope is give to the user the access to a folder that is created from an electron application and will be populated from xlsx files generated from the app during execution. Is possible to point the server response to a folder that will contain subfolders and let the user open them?

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
// This is the path where the app will save the files inside subfolders
const distFolder = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\extractions';

//
console.log('Script is running')
//
const localhost = http.createServer( (req, res) => {
    console.log(req, res)
}).listen(5000)
```